# In Flutter, how to force AWS Datastore to get data from cloud instead of from local

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, synchronization, datastore

Before I build an admin panel for my app, sometimes I have to update data from the backend using Amplify Studio.  When I do this, the only way I can get the update data to show up locally in my app is with DataStore.stop() and then DataStore.start(), which can take a bit of time and resources.

Is there a way to force Amplify to get data for a particular query from the cloud instead of from local without having to stop and start DataStore?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `Amplify DataStore` is to sync and cache most of your cloud data **locally**, hides the syncing process from you, and makes your interaction to local data just like doing realtime online query.

As per [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/flutter/#reevaluate-expressions-at-runtime), those local data will get reevaluated **only** when you restart the datastore by `.stop()` and `.start()`.

However, if your data is changing elsewhere like `Amplify Studio` other than your client app, you should actually observe your data change automatically instead of force refetching your data by restarting your datastore everytime you make a change on cloud since it is more like a business logic issue rather than caching machanism issue.

I suppose doing so with `observeQuery` inside your component:

```java
Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(
      Post.classType,
    ).listen((QuerySnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        _posts = snapshot.items;
      });
    });
```

Reference [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/real-time/q/platform/flutter/#observe-query-results-in-real-time)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a try to confirm, but I'm pretty sure I was using an observeQuery listener already